# About the image of the trace operator for Sobolev spaces.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded convex domain. Once every convex function is locally Lipschitz, we have that $\partial\Omega$ is Lipschitz, therefore, the trace operator $T: W^{1,2}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is well defined.

Suppose that $\Omega \subset \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^N:\  x= (x_1,...,x_n),\ x_1 >0\}$ and $K \subset \partial \Omega$ is a compact set, with smooth boundary such that  $K\subset \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^N :  =(0,x_1,...,x_n)\}$.

Define $h(x) = 1$ if $x \in K$ and  $h(x)=0$ if $ x \in \partial \Omega \setminus K$.

Is there a function $w \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ with $T(w) = h$? Intuitively this is true, but I don't know how to prove. Someone could help me to prove or disprove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what is the image of the trace operator?

Comment: i only know the definition $im T = T (W^{1,2}(\Omega))$ and is denoted by $H^{1\2} (\Omega)$. One time I heard that the image can be caracterized by Fourier transform.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this?

Comment: Because I want to justify (by minimization of functionals ) that the problem (the first problem mencioned in the section 13 of this paper : http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/12/87/60/PDF/fbpLaplacian.pdf ) has a unique solution in $H^1 (\Omega)$

Comment: I don't think that $h\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$, so if there is a solution for this problem, you will have to find another method to find it. You should study some book on Sobolev space, because your lack of knowledge in basic things will make things really hard for you. I suggest Leoni's book (see here http://www.amazon.com/Course-Sobolev-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847686/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1407435192&sr=8-4&keywords=sobolev+spaces)

Comment: You can try to do some calculations by your own and see what happens. Here is one characterization of $H^{1/2}$ $$H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)=\left\{f\in L^2({\partial \Omega}):\ \int_{\partial\Omega}\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+1}}dxdy<\infty\right\}$$